# Apache2 error with php7 on ubuntu 16

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

apache gives me an error when i try to start the service with php7 mod enabled.
this is the error:

```
Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled  
to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
```

anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: How did you install php?

Comment: @null05 i used     `apt-get install php7.0` and `a2enmod php7.0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to just get in running somehow and you are on a linux system(ubuntu 14.04 in this case), you can run the following commands:

`sudo a2dismod mpm_event`

`sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork`

The above two commands are basically disabling the event module and instead using the prefork module.

For systems other than linux you can see for references on how to enable disable modules and just enable/disable the mentioned modules.

Note: I don't know what can be the performance or other implications of such a change. The above solution is derived from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server#Apache_is_running_a_threaded_MPM.2C_but_your_PHP_Module_is_not_compiled_to_be_threadsafe.)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, worked perfect. Thanks!